# Why do I get current expression is not valid using JRDataSource?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to use List into the jasper report using JasperSoft Studio, but while defining dataset the JRDataSource expression is showing as invalid even after casting `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE` to the `JRXmlDataSource`(find image below).

**Expression**

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/Header/FileName")
```

**Error**

> The current expression is not valid. Please verify it!

[image: Output]

The error is looking so weird and I am not able understand it what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not worry about it, this is a [bug](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/5216) in the IDE.

If you can't close the expression editor, edit the expression manually in the xml view.